# How to restore logits

Tags: python, tensorflow

When we declare the variable logits, the variables:

fully_connected/weights_1:0,

fully_connected/biases_1:0

are created. How can I restore logits without this happening?

All global variables are:

fully_connected/weights:0, 
fully_connected/biases:0, 
beta1_power:0, 
beta2_power:0, 
fully_connected/weights/Adam:0, 
fully_connected/weights/Adam_1:0, 
fully_connected/biases/Adam:0, 
fully_connected/biases/Adam_1:0, 
fully_connected/weights_1:0, 
fully_connected/biases_1:0

```
ROOT_PATH = "datasets"
directory = TEST_DATA_SET
test_data_dir = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, directory, "Testing")

# Restore session and variables/nodes/weights
session = tf.Session()
meta_file = os.path.join("output", MODEL_DIR, "save.ckpt.meta")
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_file)
checkpoint_dir = os.path.join("output", MODEL_DIR)
new_saver.restore(session, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))

# Load the test dataset.
test_images, test_labels = load_data(test_data_dir)

# Transform the images, just like we did with the training set.
test_images32 = [skimage.transform.resize(image, (IMAGE_SCALE_SIZE_X, IMAGE_SCALE_SIZE_Y)) for image in test_images]

# Create a graph to hold the model.
graph = session.graph
#with graph.as_default():
# Placeholders for inputs and labels.
images_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, IMAGE_SCALE_SIZE_X, IMAGE_SCALE_SIZE_Y, 3])

# Flatten input from: [None, height, width, channels]
# To: [None, height * width * channels] == [None, 3072]

images_flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(images_ph)

# Fully connected layer.
# Generates logits of size [None, 62]
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(images_flat, 62, tf.nn.relu)

predicted_labels = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
Logits = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(images, weights) + biases)
```